# Drupal site source code and index.php error

Tags: php, apache, drupal, amazon-ec2, drupal-6

I am trying to migrate an existing Drupal 6 site from an IIS server onto a AWS instance and database using Linux and Apache.

I have been following the instructions on this article:

http://www.imamuseum.org/cc-mcn09.pdf

I have skipped the "Configuring MySQL" section of the article because the database I am currently using from AWS is a MySQL DB.

So far I have... 
Transferred the source code to the /ebsvol/apache/www directory.

Changed my /ebsvol/apache/www/sites/default/settings.php file under "Database URL format:" to match the new Ec2 instances database information.

Changed the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file to contain the following virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost 00.00.00.003:80> 
#ServerAdmin root
DocumentRoot /ebsvol/apache/www 
#ServerName my.test.site.edu 
#ServerAlias www.my.test.site.edu 
ErrorLog /ebsvol/apache/log/error.log 
TransferLog /ebsvol/apache/log/access.log 

<Directory /ebsvol/apache/www> 
    AllowOverride All 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I open the Ec2 instance Public DNS the page displays this error message, which turns out to be my index.php file in my Drupal source code:

```
<?php
// $Id: index.php,v 1.94 2007/12/26 08:46:48 dries Exp $

/**
* @file
* The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
*
* The routines here dispatch control to the appropriate handler, which then
* prints the appropriate page.
*
* All Drupal code is released under the GNU General Public License.
* See COPYRIGHT.txt and LICENSE.txt.
*/
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$return = menu_execute_active_handler();

// Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.
if (is_int($return)) {
switch ($return) {
case MENU_NOT_FOUND:
  drupal_not_found();
  break;
case MENU_ACCESS_DENIED:
  drupal_access_denied();
  break;
case MENU_SITE_OFFLINE:
  drupal_site_offline();
  break;
 }
}
elseif (isset($return)) {
// Print any value (including an empty string) except NULL or undefined:
print theme('page', $return);
}

drupal_page_footer();
```

Does anyone know why the Drupal site is reading only the index.php file and not the entire source code?

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If its really outputting the PHP source code, it means you haven't configured Apache to parse the scripts via PHP. The PDF you linked to doesn't say how to do that. If you are using fedora, its something like the following, though the package names may be a bit different.

```
sudo yum install php php-mysql
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Oscar. Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue. I ran this command line: cat /etc/issue and received this Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03 Kernel \r on an \m  So I'm assuming I'm not running Fedora.

Comment: I found it! The answer was in this link here: http://www.thingaweek.com/how-install-drupal-amazon-ec2 I had a couple of things wrong, first off I had to run the installs the document gave me and I also had to reboot the Apache server. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now so I'm glad I finally got this up and running :)

Comment: Great! Did you have to update the kernel? I'm curious why you had to reboot the whole server, that's pretty rare w/Apache. If you need to restart Apache or Mysql to reload your configuration, you simply restart the service. Usually via `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo system restart http.service` depending on the distribution.

Comment: I believe I was missing something within this command line: sudo yum -y install httpd mysql mysql-server php php-cli php-gd php-intl php-mbstring php-mysql php-pdo php-pear php-xml php-xmlrpc It might have been one of the multiple php installs that the command line installed onto the server. I wish I would help break this down a little more but I'm fairly new to this type of work...

Comment: I also used these command lines: sudo cp /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.old
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and changes the <Directory "/var/www/html"> to "AllowOverride All" but this is a little confusing to me because all of my source code is in the /ebsvol/apache/www/ directory...

Comment: You'll have to put your path starting with '/ebsvol/apache' in the Directory tag so that apache does what you expect.